# Asset Library not loading correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to implement the CI Asset manager found [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Asset-Manager).  After I placed the files in the correct locations and then tried to call the assets in my main view I get the following error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$assets

Filename: index/index.php

Line Number: 18

What am I forgetting to do that is causing this error?

Line 16-18 are

```
$this->load->library("Assets");

echo $this->assets->load("ie10mobile.css", "Content");
```

Comment: Paste Line Number: 18 or piece of code. Did you load asset library?

Comment: I load the asset library in line 16, which appears to run fine, and then try to use it in line 18 which is where the exception is thrown.  I have added line 16-18 to the original question above.

Comment: Is "Assets" perhaps case-sensitive? Should it maybe be lowercase?

Comment: That did not seem to fix it, the file in the libraries folder is "Assets.php" and the name of the class in the file is Assets.

Comment: You have to load library and use it in controller file, not the view.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the documentation then, I thought I could use it in the view.  So I would put the load in the controller and the echo in the view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load library and use it in controller file, not the view.

Sample controller function:

```
function index()
{
   $this->load->library("assets");

   $this->data['css'] = array(
                              $this->assets->load("ie10mobile.css", "Content"),
                              $this->assets->load("style.css", "Content"),
                              $this->assets->load("custom.css", "Content")
                             );

   $this->load->view('index_view', $this->data);
}
```

Sample view file: index_view.php

```
foreach ($css as file) {
   echo $file;
}
```

Comment: this seems to add a path to the view and not the actual css file, that I would expect.  Also I believe the view code should look like $css = $this->assets->css;
    foreach ($css as $file)